# Solr performance according to query frequency

Tags: solr

I send query to solr per 10mins (fig.1), you can see many of "invoke time" are greater than 1000ms (the "len" indicates result length form solr, every window corresponding to a server).
However, if I change query frequency - send query per 10s (fig.2), nearly all "invoke time" reduce to 10ms. Am I miss any config in solrconfig? (solr version - 3.6, all config retain its default value).

[image: send query per 10 mins]

[image: send query per 10 seconds]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for the [Solr Caching](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCaching) configuration in the solrconfig.xml file.
The Cache usually has a max size. If the max size is exceeded would make way for the New ones by removing the old and least recently used ones.
Probably, when you fire Query every 10s the result is always available in Cache and hence fetched by Solr within 10ms.
However, when you fire a query every 10mins the Cache probably has lost the entry and has to re-fetch it again, provided you have lot of queries  or the cache is invalidated within that time frame.

Check for the Cache statistics on the Solr admin page and fine the Cache settings/